# Specify web service X509 certificate endpoint identity in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I have a .NET project that invokes a web service using this configuration:

```
  <endpoint address="URL" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_MyService" contract="TokenServiceDev.MyService" name="WSHttpBinding_MyService">
    <identity>
      <certificate encodedValue="xxxx"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

As you can see a X509CertificateEndpointIdentity is specified by the `<identity>` node.

I am migrating this project to .NET Core so, given the fact that `ServiceModel.Configuration` is not supported, I need to setup this configuration programmatically.

I was looking for some guidelines and even though [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c343c266-850e-4eec-9e6f-a42b9659527c/how-to-add-identity-to-endpoint-programmatically-in-wcf?forum=wcf) is a "guide" for .NET Framework I hoped that I could easily adjust it to .NET Core. Unfortunately I can't find a way to specify the identity I need.

What should I do to specify an X509 certificate endpoint identity in .NET Core?

Comment: I havent used .NET core yet, though there are a few ways to set the certificate identity in code

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this, I just tested it with .NET Core 2.1 and managed to make it work as following.

Define a client side `X509CertificateValidator`.

```
public class MyCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    private readonly string _allowedCertificateEncodedValue;

    public MyCertificateValidator(string allowedCertificateEncodedValue)
    {
        _allowedCertificateEncodedValue = allowedCertificateEncodedValue ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("allowedCertificateEncodedValue");
    }
    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        var allowedCertificateEncodedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.RawData);
        if (_allowedCertificateEncodedValue != allowedCertificateEncodedValue)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate does not match the provided encoded value.");
        }
    }
}
```

Use the validator when creating the client.

```
var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:44300/MyService.svc");
_myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(MyServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.WSHttpBinding_IMyService, remoteAddress);
_myServiceClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
    new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom,
        CustomCertificateValidator = new MyCertificateValidator(CertificateEncodedValue)
    };

await _myServiceClient.OpenAsync();
```

Something similar to what is mentioned in the link you provided will apparantly be supported in .NET Core 3.1 as indicated on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3881).